# How to add shadow and remove bottom line in NavigationBar globally?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

So I'm looking for how can I add shadow to NavigationBar and remove the bottom black line from NavigationBar? Also if I have searchBar in NavigationBar then shadow should go below to search bar. I want to make a change globally without making a change in every viewController.

https://imgur.com/a/8ogGRaf.jpg

So I already archive these changes except add a shadow below to search controller.

1. For Shadow:

   ```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 7.0
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
   ```
2. For Remove a Bottom Bar:

   ```
   UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named:"normal")
   UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named:"normal")
   ```

This is What issue I'm getting with search Bar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXcu3.jpg

Comment: you are adding shadows to navigation bar when you should add them below search bar

Comment: You mean to like create new UIView with shadow and just add that below navigationBar?

Answer (score 1):

2.hide bottom line

```
public extension UINavigationBar {

    /// Hide line under navigation bar
    public func hideBottomHairline() {
        let navigationBarImageView = hairlineImageViewInNavigationBar(self)
        navigationBarImageView!.isHidden = true
    }

    ///  Show line under navigation bar
    public func showBottomHairline() {
        let navigationBarImageView = hairlineImageViewInNavigationBar(self)
        navigationBarImageView!.isHidden = false
    }

    fileprivate func hairlineImageViewInNavigationBar(_ view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
        if view.isKind(of: UIImageView.self) && view.bounds.height <= 1.0 {
            return (view as! UIImageView)
        }
        let subviews = (view.subviews as [UIView])
        for subview: UIView in subviews {
            if let imageView: UIImageView = hairlineImageViewInNavigationBar(subview) {
                return imageView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jone for an answer. Do you know how to archive Shadow with SearchBar?